# remove empty quotes from string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove punctuation such as " ", ' ', , `, "", '' from my string using regex. The code so far I've written only removes the ones which space between them. How do I remove the empty ones such as '',`

```
#Code
s = "hey how ' ' is the ` ` what are '' you doing `` how is everything"
s = re.sub("' '|` `|" "|""|''|``","",s)
print(s)
```

My expected outcome:

```
hey how is the what are you doing how is everything
```

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Just mentioned.

Comment: use `?` after the space to match on it, optionally. `re.sub("' ?'|\` ?\`|" ?""',"",s)`

Comment: Why use regex? You can create a new string, loop through your original string and add characters to your new string if they are not punctuation:

`newstr = ""
for char in mystr:
    if char not in ('"', ... (put punctuation characters here)):
        newstr += char`

Comment: You want to remove _`paired`_ quotes with/without whitespace in between ? You can't just match stuff like `""` without matching _all_ quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to match all such quotes:

```
r'([\'"`])\s*\1\s*'
```

**Code:**

```
>>> s = "hey how ' ' is the ` ` what are '' you doing `` how is everything"
>>> print (re.sub(r'([\'"`])\s*\1\s*', '', s))
hey how is the what are you doing how is everything
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `` ([\'"`]) ``: Match one of the given quotes and capture it in group #1
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\1`: Using back-reference of group #1 make sure we match same closing quote
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rlAstO/1)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, why not match all word characters, and then join them?

```
' '.join(re.findall('\w+',s))
# 'hey how is the what are you doing how is everything'
```